# Node Js Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-endpoints

After adding custom header(named as 'RBR') in node API and hosting as Google Endpoint in Flex Environment,getting CORS error. This node API called from Angular code. We have hosted both Angular and Node code as Google Flex Environment. API has three parameters two header value and one body value. 1.Authorization (i.e. OAuth JWT token) 2. RBR (we have custom repository for Authorization) 3. body value - Json type.

In the openapi.yaml file we have added below lines for CORS issue.

```
x-google-endpoints:
    - name: "backend-dot-myproject.appspot.com"
    allowCors: "true"
```

In node js we have added below code for CORS issue.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,authorization,rbr");
  if (req.headers.origin) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  }
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps to solve this CORS issue in NodeJs+Google Flex Environment,

1. Update your middleware code

   ```
     app.use((req, res, next) => {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
       "Origin, X-Requeted-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, RBR");
     if (req.headers.origin) {
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
     }
     if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
       return res.status(200).json({});
     }
     next();
    });
   ```
2. In the app.yaml

```
handlers:
    - url: /
      static_dir: /
      http_headers:
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.In terminal: `npm i cors --save`

2.In you code:

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: I tried with this method, I got below error message:                                          
 ** Failed to load <API URL>: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin <App URL> is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401**.

Comment: res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-*, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

Try this.

Comment: Our problem starts when we are adding custom header(rbr) in the header section while calling the API (node endpoint). Please note that when we remove the custom header, API call is working fine.